# kubefwd with microk8s: 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: microk8s

Trying to run [kubefwd](https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd) with `microk8s`:

```
sudo kubefwd svc
```

It fails with an error:

```
Runtime error: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20191108070106-f8f007fd456c/tools/cache/reflector.go:108: 
Failed to list *v1.Service: Get "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/services?
limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 3):

`kubefwd` does not use `kubectl`, only the configuration files, so ask `microk8s` to write its config as its [README.md says](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/blob/b2b55883ac1636eca8d0c07c84bbec9452ed1b68/README.md):

```
sudo microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config
```

After this step `kubefwd` should work.