# Error running Stern to look at microk8s logs

Tags: ubuntu, microk8s

I’m getting an error when running stern  as it didn’t have a config file. I gave it the .kube/config file but this errors, “..signed by an unknown authority” I need to generate a new config file for Stern to run on microk8s.kubectrl but can’t find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that, the issues turns out to be that Stern does not like my self signed certs.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question fully. Today I had an issue of using stern in an env with microk8s. I looked around and I saw a similar error to the one I was getting in [kubefwd with microk8s: 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828007/kubefwd-with-microk8s-127-0-0-18080-connect-connection-refused)

So to get stern working with microk8s I had to do a

```
     microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config
```

I had an alias set for microk8s.kubectl as kubectl. I dont think this matters but just mentioning.